# Como sumar valor numerico que aparece ya en un input readonly y que ese valor salga en otro input

Tags: javascript, html, input, readonly

Tengo un archivo html donde hay inputs que los he sumado con javascript y el resultado se muestra en otro inpyt pero este es readonly, en total son 3 input readonly de 3 subtotales, y necesito sumar esos subtotales pero como los input son readonly no los puedo sumar con onkeyup y no se con que funcion de javascript los puedo sumar

Comment: Puedes compartir el código que llevas hecho? así será mas fácil ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar `document.getElementById('id-del-input').value` para obtener el valor de un input. Sin ver el código no te puedo ayudar mucho más